# amCharts - Not displaying in jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, charts

I searched a solution for this problem and I came to this: http://blog.amcharts.com/2012/08/displaying-javascript-charts-in-tabs-or.html which seems easy enough. But when I apply that piece of code according to the example, the tabs stop working, I can't switch between them.

In URL there is some change according on what tab I clicked, but content isn't switching, tabs are not also. I can't figure it out even after two days of searching. Structure of my code is like that:

1. I got file with html code, JS code for tabs (just like in the example on amCharts site), plus function for loading content to the tabs from another files:

   ```
   $("#zalozka_kalkulace").click(function(){
       $("#detail_ceny_switch_ceny").addClass("open");
       $("#detail_ceny_switch_ceny").removeClass("rucka");
       $("#detail_ceny_switch_ceny").css({ 'height' : '478px', 'margin-bottom' : '-360px', 'margin-right' : '-475px', 'float' : 'left', 'top' : '-360px', 'width' : '871px' });
       if($("#detail_ceny_grafy_kalkulaci").html() == ""){
           $("#detail_ceny_grafy_kalkulaci").load('./safe/kalkulace_grafy_all.php?k_stupen=<? echo $k_stupen; ?>&k_polozka=<? echo $co; ?>',function(){
               $("#detail_ceny_grafy_kalkulaci").removeClass("hidden");
           });
       }else{
           $("#detail_ceny_grafy_kalkulaci").removeClass("hidden");
       }
   });
   ```
2. I got another file which contains everything that is displayed in the tab. That means div  in which the chart should be displayed, plus JS code for chart data and chart itself (just like in the example on amCharts site)

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I got everything like in that example (I copied that) but just separated in the two files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work like that. The JavaScript code loaded through jQuery.load does not get executed.

The solution would be to load HTML and JavaScript part separately using two AJAX requests: jQuery.load for HTML and [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for JavaScript part. Or, even better, modify the loaded script to include the HTML items, too.

I.e.:

**In the main script:**

```
$.getScript("./safe/kalkulace_grafy_all.php?k_stupen=<? echo $k_stupen; ?>&k_polozka=<? echo $co; ?>',function(){
  $("#detail_ceny_grafy_kalkulaci").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

**In the loaded script:**

```
$("#detail_ceny_grafy_kalkulaci").html('<div id="chartdiv"></div>');
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
....
chart.write("chartdiv");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I still can´t get it to work. In the main script I used your piece of code instead of line with jQuery.load. In the loaded script I just added jQuery.html... In result there is nothing displayed in the tab...